# Cuboid with natural number diagonals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to solve the unsolved problem of finding a cuboid with natural no. sides, face diagonals and space diagonal just as a pastime. I came across the following question.

$A=(m-n)(x-y)$

$B=2(x-y)\sqrt{mn}$

$C=2(m-n)\sqrt{xy}$

$m>n$ and $x>y$ (m,n,x,y are natural nos.)

Can either of these conditions (or both) be fulfilled?

$\sqrt{B^2+C^2}$ is a natural no.

$\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}$ is a natural no.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick

- Martin-Blas Perez Pinilla